# Linux Fiber Channel Host Setup Basic

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, hba

I've been googling for about 4 hours now with no luck. I am trying to setup a Linux server running Oracle Server 6.3 as a  Fiber Channel host. And then connect it to a Dell Compellent Fibre Channel Host contain a 500GB Volume.

The Oracle server itself contains two Brocade 815 FC HBAs. I've discovered their WWN(I think) via

```
cat /sys/class/fc_host/host1/port_name
0x100000051efc3d85

cat /sys/class/fc_host/host2/port_name
0x100000051efc3d9f
```

The next part is where I am at a loss. I've used iSCSI before...is FC the same deal where you have an initiator and a target? If so where do I specific that in linux?

I'm also new to Fiber Channel as a protocol, so i am unsure what is needed to make a transaction? WWN and port ID? Similar to IP:Port combination in the Ethernet world.

I've read alot regarding using systool, multipath, fc_transport commands, however none of these is recognized as a valid command from Oracle Server 6.3

Appreciate the guidance and assistance.

I installed sccsi-target-utils and can now run rescan-scsi-bus and sg_map -x.

```
rescan-scsi-bus.sh -l -w -r
Host adapter 0 (megaraid_sas) found.
Host adapter 1 ((null)) found.
Host adapter 2 ((null)) found.
Host adapter 3 (ata_piix) found.
Host adapter 4 (ata_piix) found.
Scanning SCSI subsystem for new devices
 and remove devices that have disappeared
Scanning host 0 for  SCSI target IDs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15, LUNs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Scanning for device 0 2 0 0 ....
OLD: Host: scsi0 Channel: 02 Id: 00 Lun: 00
      Vendor: DELL     Model: PERC H700        Rev: 2.30
      Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Scanning for device 0 2 1 0 ...
OLD: Host: scsi0 Channel: 02 Id: 01 Lun: 00
      Vendor: DELL     Model: PERC H700        Rev: 2.30
      Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Scanning host 1 for  all SCSI target IDs, LUNs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Scanning for device 1 0 3 1 ...
OLD: Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 01
      Vendor: COMPELNT Model: Compellent Vol   Rev: 0505
      Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Scanning host 2 for  all SCSI target IDs, LUNs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Scanning host 3 for  all SCSI target IDs, LUNs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Scanning for device 3 0 0 0 ...
REM: Host: scsi3 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
DEL:  Vendor: TEAC     Model: DVD-ROM DV-28SW  Rev: R.2A
      Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Scanning host 4 channels  0 for  SCSI target IDs  0, LUNs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 new device(s) found.
1 device(s) removed.
```

and

```
sg_map -x
/dev/sg0  0 0 32 0  13
/dev/sg1  0 2 0 0  0  /dev/sda
/dev/sg2  0 2 1 0  0  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg4  1 0 3 1  0  /dev/sdc
```

multipath -ll

```
 multipath -ll
Dec 19 09:33:57 | DM multipath kernel driver not loaded
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 14, invalid keyword: device
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 15, invalid keyword: vendor
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 16, invalid keyword: product
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 17, invalid keyword: path_grouping_policy
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 18, invalid keyword: getuid_callout
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 19, invalid keyword: path_selector
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 20, invalid keyword: path_checker
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 21, invalid keyword: features
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 22, invalid keyword: hardware_handler
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 23, invalid keyword: failback
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 24, invalid keyword: rr_weight
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 25, invalid keyword: no_path_retry
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 26, invalid keyword: rr_min_io
Dec 19 09:33:57 | multipath.conf line 27, invalid keyword: }
Dec 19 09:33:57 | DM multipath kernel driver not loaded
```

I'm not sure what this all means...

Comment: Do you have Oracle Support? If yes.  Ask them. That's what you're paying for.  If not: Why not? (or why are you using "Oracle Server")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc are the two paths to the SAN volume. So you *could* pick one of those partition it, format it and mount it directly. However this is a bad idea since you won't have any failover support.

The next step is to get `device-mapper-multipath` installed and configured - see [this RedHat doc](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/DM_Multipath/mpio_setup.html) (I am assuming Oracle 6 is the same as RHEL 6). I am not sure exactly what you need in `/etc/multipath.conf` for a Dell Compellent array. This may work:

```
device {
vendor "COMPELNT"
product "Compellent Vol"
path_grouping_policy multibus
getuid_callout "/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"
path_selector "round-robin 0"
path_checker tur
features "0"
hardware_handler "0"
failback immediate
rr_weight uniform
no_path_retry queue
rr_min_io 1000
}
```

It's from http://pig.made-it.com/multipath.html.

Once you have the multipathd service started, you should be able to run `multipath -ll` and see both paths to the SAN. In addition, the mpath names in this output should map to entries in `/dev/mapper`. The mapper disks *are* the paths are the ones you want to format, partition, mount, etc.

FYI, you don't have to mess with all the SCSI rescan stuff. If you just echo a 1 to both of the FC host sys entries, the /dev/sdx entries will show up. Something like `echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/host1/issue_lip` will do it. Host numbers may be different on your systel. Make sure you echo to all the host ports too.

Comment: -bash: /sys/class/fc_host/host1/issue_lip: No such file or directory

Comment: May be a different host number. Do you have anything in `/sys/class/fc_host/host`? I have seen host5 and host6 on some systems.

Comment: The only two hosts i have are fc_host\host1 and fc_host\host2